# Do I need to remove all "java|jre" packages from my system to be secure from java vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, java

Currently I have these installed on my Scientific Linux 6.3:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | egrep -i 'java|jre'
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.7.1.el6_3.x86_64
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.56.1.11.8.el6_3.x86_64
tzdata-java-2012j-1.el6.noarch
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Do I need to remove then to be safe from the recent Java vulnerabilities? (If I try to remove the java-1.6.0-openjdk.. then it wants to remove libreoffice too..)

Or the vulnerabilities are just related to java webbrowser plugins?

Comment: Use Firefox + NoScript, enable click-to-play. While you are "securing" you computer, do not forget to replace the rotten door to your home by a stronger one.

Comment: The answer depends a little bit on why you installed java (what applications that you use need it - are these applications internal, or external internet applications). And it depends on whether you use a proxy for internet-access or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most vulnerabilities are related to the webbrowser-plugin. In most (all?) cases you must (actively) execute malicious java-code that exploits these weaknesses.

From the perspective of an attacker this is most easily done by putting that code into the web and luring you onto it, so you execute that code.

A more subtle approach might be to upload some java code into your application and have it execute that code (by exploiting other weaknesses like code-injections).

So if you have neither a running, externally exposed application that can execute code, nor have a browser installed, you should be pretty safe.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to latest vulnerabilities about jdks (those went public on Feb, 2013), it's not necessary.

Just disable it the java plugin in your browser.